# AFP / Apple Filling Protocol aka Netatalk access over Internet

Tags: network-share, tcpip, daemon, afp, netatalk

I got a simple cloud server and thought it would be nice to have mac native afp 
Volumes accesss. Installed Netatalk and this seems to work pretty nice.

No sensitive data or something but I don't like to wake up someday and have 
my www docs rm-rfed by some kid h4x0r.

**Q1:** Is afp encrypted?

**Q2:** How can I make it (semi)secure?

**Q3:** Does VPN makes sense for this?

**Q4:** What would you do to get afp working over net?

Opening any service meant for Lan only is a basic flaw, i know - but me be ignorant about it. According to [Apple Dev](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/AFP/Concepts/Concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000854-CH3-SW1) only the authentication is encrypted or am I mssing something?

Answer (score 0):

1. AFP is not encrypted.
2. Use a VPN.
3. Yes, and is the only way I'd consider making either AFP or CIFS shares accessible over the public internet.
4. See #2.